# Is there a way to retrieve all index created on server regions using Java?

Tags: java, jmx, gemfire

I created regions with indexes using gfsh. I am trying to get those list of indexes based on region and server. I used mbean "CacheServerMXBean" to get list of indexes based on server. But I don't get name of region on which index is created. Is there a option to get index details along with region and server name?

I also tried using new ClientCacheFactory().addPoolLocator("localhost", 10334).create().getLocalQueryService().getIndexes(); 
Resultset is empty

1) ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory().addPoolLocator("localhost", 10334).create();

```
    Region<String, Object> region1 = cache
              .<String, Object>createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
              .create("region_local");
```

region1.getRegionService().getQueryService().getIndexes();

Error: Index operation not supported on server region.

2) new ClientCacheFactory().addPoolLocator("localhost", 10334).create().getLocalQueryService().getIndexes(); 
Output : Empty array

3) (Working code)

ObjectName objName = new ObjectName(
                String.format(String.format("GemFire:service=CacheServer,port=%s,type=Member,member=%s", serverPort, serverName)));
        CacheServerMBean cacheBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbeanConnection, objName, CacheServerMBean.class);

```
    cacheBean.getIndexList();
```

Output: This gives me list of indexes. But I am trying to find a way to get region details on which these indexes were created.

GFSH Command: create index --name=myKeyIndex_local --expression=region_local.Id --region=region_local --type=key

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no way of getting the full index metadata through JMX, internally the code is just extracting the name of the index and returning only that particular data to the caller (even though it has the actual member and region name as well).

That said, this information can be obtained through Java using something similar to what you posted, **but the code should be executed on server side**:

```
for (final Index index : cache.getQueryService().getIndexes()) {
  System.out.println(index.getName() + " " + index.getRegion().getName());  
}
```

You could embed this logic within a `function` and execute the actual `function` from a client to retrieve this data, which is exactly what `gfsh` does when you execute the `list indexes` [command](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/054687a17ccd06ce38f73a59cc4310dd9b5b1bd5/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/ListIndexCommand.java#L99).

Hope this helps. Cheers.